# Проблема с import в самописном модуле python

Tags: python

Написал свой модуль:

```
import time


sec =  int(input())
min =  int(input())
hour = int(input())

if sec == '':
     sec = None
     exit(0)
if min == '':
    min = None
    exit(0)
if hour == '':
    hour = None
    exit(0) 
    

def time_to_seconds():
    second = (min * 60) + (hour * 3600) + sec
    return second
    
print(time_to_seconds())
time_to_find = int(input())

if time_to_find == '':
     time_to_find = None
     exit(0)

def time_from_seconds():

   time_output = time.strftime("%H Hours %M Minutes %S Seconds", time.gmtime(time_to_find)) 
   return time_output

print(time_from_seconds())
```

Сделал файл в котором написал:

```
import timecount
```

Вывод такой:

```
4
4
4
14644
4
00 Hours 00 Minutes 04 Seconds
```

Первые 3 строки - ввод переменных `sec` `min` и `hour`. 4  строка - вывод секунд. 5 строка - ввод секунд. 6 строка - вывод времени.
Как вы поняли выполняется весь модуль хотя я его только импортировал.

[image: import time ничего не выводит]

Comment: А как с вашей точки зрения должен вести себя файл после импорта? Лежать себе тихонечко и ждать, пока его позовут:-)?

Comment: Когда я импортирую что угодно еще оно лежит и ждет. Пример: import time ничего не делает

Comment: Потому что в `timе` нету строк, в которых что-нибудь да выводится через `print`, там все функции ожидают своего вызова, у Вас же они выполняются сразу, не по требованию

Comment: Андрей, вы загляните в этот `time`. Там же, наверняка, просто что-то типа набора функций, вот они и ждут вашего обращения. В общем, он так и должен себя вести. Советую почитать немного об импорте, там может быть ещё ряд каких-то моментов вам важных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При импортировании модуля исполняется весь код модуля.

Но этого можно избежать. При этом оставив возможность прямого запуска. Для этого оберните исполняемый код в такое условие:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Ваш модуль в итоге может выглядеть так:

```py
import time


def time_to_seconds():
    second = (min * 60) + (hour * 3600) + sec
    return second


def time_from_seconds():
   time_output = time.strftime("%H Hours %M Minutes %S Seconds", time.gmtime(time_to_find)) 
   return time_output


def main():
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```